How to deploy war file on tomcat application server
I have runnable springboot (2.4) Java (8) project and it works fine with embedded tomcat (10) with .jar extension. I need to run the same project on the tomcat application server but after I changed it into .war and deployed into tomcat application server it gives 404 error message. Is there anything I need to do additional works to deploy on tomcat applications server?
My main class as per below,
@ComponentScan("com.example.testproject")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@Slf4j
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return configureApplication(builder);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ApplicationStarter.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
    }
    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {    
        return builder.sources(ApplicationStarter.class);
    }
}

and I added below dependency also,
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-testproject</version>
<packaging>war</packaging> // earlier it was jar and with embedded tomcat its working 


"changed it into war" this is not enough for us to understand what you did. Share the exact steps you took to create the war. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Which Spring Boot version, Which tomcat version. Far too litlle information. There are also a bunch of annotations on your class that shouldn't be there (which makes me wonder what other things did you add to "make it work"). The annotations like @ComponentScan (assuming the ApplicationStarter is in com.example.testproject as recommended), @EnableAutoConfiguration.

Hi  its springboot 2.4 and tomcat 10 and i removed @EnableAutoConfiguration but still same

Spring Boot 2.4 doesn't work with Tomcat 10. Spring Boot 2.4 is for JavaEE which is Tomcat 9 or earlier, Tomcat10 is JakartaEE and is to be used with Spring Boot 3+.

You should also say that tomcat will be provided in your pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


In addition to the steps you did already you should add this to the pom.xml:
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

By defining the scope = provided you prevent Spring Boot of starting the embedded Tomcat. After re-packaging the project you can copy the WAR file to your external Tomcat and restart it.
Based on: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy
